# Database migration syntax

Tags: postgresql, database-migration

I am unsure how to rewrite this. I understand the issue or at least I think I do. I am unable to use instances of t before it is defined by the follow "AS" statement. How can I resolve this so that so that it works the same way without using the instance of t before definition?

The error that I am getting thrown from the converter is "unable to convert .t"

Converted code

```
    INSERT INTO t$trades_long (portfolio_name, fund, cusip, td_num, desc_instmt, trd_price, trd_trade_dt, t.trd_settle_dt, trd_counterparty, trd_td_par, tran_type, sec_type, trd_type, t.trd_trader)
    SELECT
        p.portfolio_name, t.fund, t.cusip, t.td_num, a.desc_instmt, t.trd_price, t.trd_trade_dt, t.trd_settle_dt, t.trd_counterparty, t.trd_td_par, t.tran_type, a.sec_type, 'long' AS trd_type, trd_trader
        FROM pfi_pilot.br_transaction AS t, pfi_pilot.br_portfolio_group AS p, pfi_pilot.br_asset AS a
        WHERE t.fund = p.fund AND p.portfolio_group = 'ALL_FUNDS' AND t.cusip = a.cusip AND t.tran_type IN ('BUY', 'SELL', 'ISSUE', 'ALLOC') AND t.trd_status <> 'C' AND a.sm_sec_group NOT IN ('CASH', 'FUTURE', 'FX', 'FUND', 'SWAP', 'OPTION') AND a.sec_type != 'MBS_TBA' AND t.trd_counterparty NOT IN ('IFUND', 'GHOST', 'SPO', 'SPOBO', 'CONV', 'ASSGN') AND t.trd_trade_dt >= par_from_dt AND t.trd_trade_dt <= par_to_dt AND t.cusip NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT
            cusip
            FROM pfi_pilot.br_asset
            WHERE (COALESCE(risk_country, country) = 'US' AND sm_sec_type IN ('GOVT', 'TBILL'))) AND t.trd_td_par > 0;
```

Original code

```
insert into #trades_long(portfolio_name, fund, cusip, td_num, desc_instmt, trd_price, trd_trade_dt, t.trd_settle_dt,
trd_counterparty, trd_td_par, tran_type , sec_type, trd_type, t.trd_trader)

select p.portfolio_name, t.fund, t.cusip, t.td_num, a.desc_instmt, t.trd_price, t.trd_trade_dt, t.trd_settle_dt, 
t.trd_counterparty, t.trd_td_par, t.tran_type, a.sec_type,'long' as trd_type, trd_trader
from br_transaction t, br_portfolio_group p, br_asset a
where t.fund = p.fund 
and p.portfolio_group = 'ALL_FUNDS'
and t.cusip = a.cusip
and t.tran_type in ('BUY','SELL','ISSUE','ALLOC')
and t.trd_status <> 'C'
and a.sm_sec_group not in ('CASH','FUTURE','FX','FUND','SWAP','OPTION')     
and a.sec_type != 'MBS_TBA'
and t.trd_counterparty not in ('IFUND','GHOST','SPO','SPOBO','CONV','ASSGN')
and t.trd_trade_dt >= @from_dt 
and t.trd_trade_dt <= @to_dt
and t.cusip not in (select distinct cusip from br_asset where (isnull(risk_country,country) = 'US' 
                    and sm_sec_type in ('GOVT','TBILL')))
and t.trd_td_par > 0
```

Comment: try without "AS". Like this: "FROM pfi_pilot.br_transaction  t, pfi_pilot.br_portfolio_group p, pfi_pilot.br_asset a"

Comment: Thank you for the reply.

when try that I it still fails the same way. The .t is not resolving in the "INSERT INTO" part of the code. `INSERT INTO t$trades_long (portfolio_name, fund, cusip, td_num, desc_instmt, trd_price, trd_trade_dt, t.trd_settle_dt, trd_counterparty, trd_td_par, tran_type, sec_type, trd_type, t.trd_trader)`
    
 
The error coming back is `""message_text": "column \"t\" of relation \"t$trades_long\" does not exist""`

Comment: Does the column name actually have a period in it?  If so, use double quotes around it like:  `"t.trd_trader"`.  If not, then I have no idea why you would alias a column in the column list of an insert.

Comment: You have `t.trd_settle_dt` in the list of column names being inserted *insert into #trades_long(..., t.trd_settle_dt, ...)*. That is invalid, the column names list contains **only** column names from the table. `t.trd_settle_dt` should just be `trd_settle_dt` assuming it follows the same format as the other columns.